# Understanding new gcc prologue

Tags: gcc, assembly, intel

I was wondering why did gcc introduce a new prologue (and epilogue as well) to functions - especially main() since I only analyzed it. For example, before, it was:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 0x... ; Allocate memory space into the stack

; ... Some code

; Epilogue
leave
ret
```

Now this is a bit more complex (to understand, at least):

```
lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
and    esp,0xfffffff0
push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
push   ebp
mov    ebp,esp
push   ecx
sub    esp,0x64

; Some code

; Epilogue
add    esp,0x64
pop    ecx
pop    ebp
lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
ret
```

I understand what it concretely does, but I cannot figure out the **purpose**
 of it. Is it to render the exploitation (stack overflow) attempts a bit more tricky? Another calling convention? Just to make the stack safer? (Since I met this stuff in a wargame)

Finally, my gcc version is :
    gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of GCC are you comparing 4.3.2 with?

Comment: No one especially, but I can remember that old ones did not put such prologue / epilogue...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose is to align the stack on a 16-byte boundary.

Comment: Ok, after analyzing the instructions around, it seems quite obvious because the "and esp, 0xfffffff0" alone wouldn't be sufficient. Cheers Raymond!

Comment: And the *reason* for aligning on 16 bytes is the alignment requirements for SSE instructions which might operate on stack variables. Normally such prolog is used only for the entry point (main) or exported functions in shared objects; the rest of code assumes that the caller took care of it.

Comment: Thank you Igor, this is getting more and more obvious now.