# What is the purpose of the sub esp, eax in function prologue?

Tags: gcc, assembly

I have a simple function prologue (for a C program's main(), no arguments) that looks like this:

```
0x8048384     push ebp                     
0x8048385     mov ebp,esp               
0x8048387     sub esp,0x18                
0x804838a     and esp,0xfffffff0          
0x804838d     mov eax,0x0                 
0x8048392     sub esp,eax
```

I'm curious, what is the purpose of setting eax to 0 and then subtracting it from esp? It seems like wasted instructions. Are there other examples of gcc generated function prologues where this would have more meaning (or eax would have a value other than 0)?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The entirety of the C program (from "The Art of Explotation" book) is below. It was compiled only with the -g option, using gcc 3.3.6 (yeah, way old, but it came on a virtual machine image). It's supposed to be a lesson about the stack.

```
void test_function(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int flag;
    char buffer[10];
    flag 31337;
    buffer[0] = 'A';
}

int main()
{
    test_function(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Edit #2 disassembly (gcc -g -S -masm=intel) provided:

```
    .file   "stack_example.c"
    .intel_syntax
    .file 1 "stack_example.c"
    .section    .debug_abbrev,"",@progbits
.Ldebug_abbrev0:
    .section    .debug_info,"",@progbits
.Ldebug_info0:
    .section    .debug_line,"",@progbits
.Ldebug_line0:
    .text
.Ltext0:
.globl test_function
    .type   test_function, @function
test_function:
.LFB3:
    .loc 1 1 0
    push    %ebp
.LCFI0:
    mov %ebp, %esp
.LCFI1:
    sub %esp, 40
.LCFI2:
    .loc 1 5 0
.LBB2:
    mov DWORD PTR [%ebp-12], 31337
    .loc 1 6 0
    mov BYTE PTR [%ebp-40], 65
    .loc 1 7 0
    leave
    ret
.LBE2:
.LFE3:
    .size   test_function, .-test_function
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB5:
    .loc 1 9 0
    push    %ebp
.LCFI3:
    mov %ebp, %esp
.LCFI4:
    sub %esp, 24
.LCFI5:
    and %esp, -16
    mov %eax, 0
    sub %esp, %eax
    .loc 1 10 0
    mov DWORD PTR [%esp+12], 4
    mov DWORD PTR [%esp+8], 3
    mov DWORD PTR [%esp+4], 2
    mov DWORD PTR [%esp], 1
    call    test_function
    .loc 1 11 0
    leave
    ret
.LFE5:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .debug_frame,"",@progbits
.Lframe0:
    .long   .LECIE0-.LSCIE0
.LSCIE0:
    .long   0xffffffff
    .byte   0x1
    .string ""
    .uleb128 0x1
    .sleb128 -4
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0xc
    .uleb128 0x4
    .uleb128 0x4
    .byte   0x88
    .uleb128 0x1
    .align 4
.LECIE0:
.LSFDE0:
    .long   .LEFDE0-.LASFDE0
.LASFDE0:
    .long   .Lframe0
    .long   .LFB3
    .long   .LFE3-.LFB3
    .byte   0x4
    .long   .LCFI0-.LFB3
    .byte   0xe
    .uleb128 0x8
    .byte   0x85
    .uleb128 0x2
    .byte   0x4
    .long   .LCFI1-.LCFI0
    .byte   0xd
    .uleb128 0x5
    .align 4
.LEFDE0:
.LSFDE2:
    .long   .LEFDE2-.LASFDE2
.LASFDE2:
    .long   .Lframe0
    .long   .LFB5
    .long   .LFE5-.LFB5
    .byte   0x4
    .long   .LCFI3-.LFB5
    .byte   0xe
    .uleb128 0x8
    .byte   0x85
    .uleb128 0x2
    .byte   0x4
    .long   .LCFI4-.LCFI3
    .byte   0xd
    .uleb128 0x5
    .align 4
.LEFDE2:
    .text
.Letext0:
    .section    .debug_info
    .long   0x118
    .value  0x2
    .long   .Ldebug_abbrev0
    .byte   0x4
    .uleb128 0x1
    .long   .Ldebug_line0
    .long   .Letext0
    .long   .Ltext0
    .string "stack_example.c"
    .string "/home/booksrc"
    .string "GNU C 3.3.6 (Ubuntu 1:3.3.6-15ubuntu1)"
    .byte   0x1
    .uleb128 0x2
    .long   0xd5
    .byte   0x1
    .string "test_function"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x1
    .long   .LFB3
    .long   .LFE3
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x55
    .uleb128 0x3
    .string "a"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x1
    .long   0xd5
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x91
    .sleb128 8
    .uleb128 0x3
    .string "b"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x1
    .long   0xd5
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x91
    .sleb128 12
    .uleb128 0x3
    .string "c"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x1
    .long   0xd5
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x91
    .sleb128 16
    .uleb128 0x3
    .string "d"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x1
    .long   0xd5
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x91
    .sleb128 20
    .uleb128 0x4
    .string "flag"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x2
    .long   0xd5
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x91
    .sleb128 -12
    .uleb128 0x4
    .string "buffer"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x3
    .long   0xdc
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x91
    .sleb128 -40
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x5
    .string "int"
    .byte   0x4
    .byte   0x5
    .uleb128 0x6
    .long   0xec
    .long   0xfc
    .uleb128 0x7
    .long   0xec
    .byte   0x9
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x5
    .string "unsigned int"
    .byte   0x4
    .byte   0x7
    .uleb128 0x5
    .string "char"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x6
    .uleb128 0x8
    .byte   0x1
    .string "main"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x9
    .long   0xd5
    .long   .LFB5
    .long   .LFE5
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x55
    .byte   0x0
    .section    .debug_abbrev
    .uleb128 0x1
    .uleb128 0x11
    .byte   0x1
    .uleb128 0x10
    .uleb128 0x6
    .uleb128 0x12
    .uleb128 0x1
    .uleb128 0x11
    .uleb128 0x1
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0x8
    .uleb128 0x1b
    .uleb128 0x8
    .uleb128 0x25
    .uleb128 0x8
    .uleb128 0x13
    .uleb128 0xb
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x2
    .uleb128 0x2e
    .byte   0x1
    .uleb128 0x1
    .uleb128 0x13
    .uleb128 0x3f
    .uleb128 0xc
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0x8
    .uleb128 0x3a
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x3b
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x27
    .uleb128 0xc
    .uleb128 0x11
    .uleb128 0x1
    .uleb128 0x12
    .uleb128 0x1
    .uleb128 0x40
    .uleb128 0xa
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0x5
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0x8
    .uleb128 0x3a
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x3b
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x49
    .uleb128 0x13
    .uleb128 0x2
    .uleb128 0xa
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x4
    .uleb128 0x34
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0x8
    .uleb128 0x3a
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x3b
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x49
    .uleb128 0x13
    .uleb128 0x2
    .uleb128 0xa
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x5
    .uleb128 0x24
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0x8
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x3e
    .uleb128 0xb
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x6
    .uleb128 0x1
    .byte   0x1
    .uleb128 0x1
    .uleb128 0x13
    .uleb128 0x49
    .uleb128 0x13
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x7
    .uleb128 0x21
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x49
    .uleb128 0x13
    .uleb128 0x2f
    .uleb128 0xb
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x8
    .uleb128 0x2e
    .byte   0x0
    .uleb128 0x3f
    .uleb128 0xc
    .uleb128 0x3
    .uleb128 0x8
    .uleb128 0x3a
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x3b
    .uleb128 0xb
    .uleb128 0x49
    .uleb128 0x13
    .uleb128 0x11
    .uleb128 0x1
    .uleb128 0x12
    .uleb128 0x1
    .uleb128 0x40
    .uleb128 0xa
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x0
    .section    .debug_pubnames,"",@progbits
    .long   0x29
    .value  0x2
    .long   .Ldebug_info0
    .long   0x11c
    .long   0x63
    .string "test_function"
    .long   0x104
    .string "main"
    .long   0x0
    .section    .debug_aranges,"",@progbits
    .long   0x1c
    .value  0x2
    .long   .Ldebug_info0
    .byte   0x4
    .byte   0x0
    .value  0x0
    .value  0x0
    .long   .Ltext0
    .long   .Letext0-.Ltext0
    .long   0x0
    .long   0x0
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 3.3.6 (Ubuntu 1:3.3.6-15ubuntu1)"
```

Comment: What optimization level did you use? It could be that the compiler generated "boiler-plate" for creating a stack frame (for automatic storage) but since you didn't declare local variables the size is 0.  That goes away with optimization (dead-code elimination).

Comment: According to this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886429/understanding-new-gcc-prologue, it's to align it to a 16 byte boundary, which SSE instructions require. See the linked answer for more.

Comment: The 'and esp,0xfffffff0' is doing the alignment, the OP was asking about the 'mov eax,0x0' and 'sub esp,eax'.

Comment: @amdn - I think you may be correct. I only compiled this with the -g option (no optimizations). Still, I'm curious when gcc would give eax a value other than '0'. The two instructions seem useless, since if you need to allocate more memory for the variables, you can do that with the sub esp instruction.

Comment: It looks like gcc recognized that those local variables were unused, so it didn't allocate storage for them.  Try compiling with -O3 and see what it does.

Comment: can you provide a full disassembly? I have not been able to reproduce the given function header. (gcc 4.8.2 does nothing surprising with `-g` and optimizes away everything with `-O1 -g`)

Comment: you can use a commandline like `gcc -g test.cpp -S -masm=intel -o test.asm -fwhole-program`

Comment: Full disassembly provided

Comment: @Maxthecat sorry, I have to give up. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @example - No worries! Thanks for taking a stab at it! I'm glad to see that the newer gcc omits them. It sounds like it's an artifact of the older gcc version.

Answer (score 1):

**update**

After seeing the source code and the full disassembly I have no more idea why this part (`mov eax, 0; sub esp,eax`) should be there. I see no reasonable generalization that the compiler might have been aiming for. I am sure, that any optimization level would remove the lines and newer versions of the gcc seem to omit them.

It is possible that older versions of the gcc had such an extended function header (though I see no reason for them) or that these commands are some artifact of gcc's internal representations. Maybe someone who knows more about gcc's history can answer this...

---

**old answer**

I do not know this for sure, but a possible explanation is

```
push ebp           ; store stack pointer          
mov ebp,esp        ; create local frame
sub esp,0x18       ; make room for some variables + empty space to...        
and esp,0xfffffff0 ; ... align the stack-pointer 
mov eax,0x0        ; eax = sizeof(someClass)
sub esp,eax        ; create room for one object on the aligned stack
```

This of course assumes that there already were some optimizations (like reducing the objects size to 0, maybe some inlining eg. of `alloca`), but that the gcc did not fully optimize the code. Maybe due to some flags like `-Og`, `-g` etc.

Comment: @ooga I don't see why one would have to act on `esp` in that case. It would be nice to see the corresponding source. I imagine that there is an `alloca` call somewhere in the beginnning, that was inlined...

Comment: I agree. More info is needed.

Comment: @ooga - more info added :) Let me know if it's still clear as mud.

Comment: I'm confused about the 6 bytes created by `sub esp, 0x18`. The `main` function has no local variables, are the 6 bytes for the implicit arguments `argc` and `argv`?