# Simple shellcode not working

Tags: c, gcc, shellcode

I have the following code which is supposed to drop a shell, however, after I run the code nothing appears to happen. Here is the code that I have. This was taken from the shellcoder's handbook.

`

```
char shellcode[] = 
    "\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46"
    "\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1"
    "\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";
int main()
{
    int *ret;
    ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
    (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}`
```

I compile it using `gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack shellcode.c -o shellcode`

When I run it the following happens.
[image: Actual results of shellcode]

The expected result is the following. 
[image: Expected results of shellcode]

Here is the code that produces the above results:

```
int main()
{
  char *name[2];

  name[0] = "/bin/sh";
  name[1] = 0x0;
  execve(name[0], name, 0x0);
  exit(0);

}
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I am using Ubuntu on Windows 10. This might not effect my results but I have disabled ASLR. That might be an issue. I have not tried this on a VM just yet. I wanted to try and figure out why this is not working before I did that. If this is unclear please let me know and I will be happy to clarify any details.

I appreciate all of your help in advance.

--UPDATE--

I was able to get the assembly instructions from the shellcode I provided.

[image: Assembly from above shellcode]

Does anyone see any issues that would cause a shell not to be dropped?

Comment: what is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: How do you run Ubuntu on Windows 10 without a VM?

Comment: @jwdonahue: There's a Linux (Ubuntu) subsystem on Windows 10.

Comment: @jwdonahue what he said and the output of uname -a is `Linux DESKTOP-P4KG81D 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #48-Microsoft Fri Apr 27 18:06:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: I believe the reference is using Debian 3.1r4 if that helps at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of a colleague we were able to figure out why the shellcode was not executing. The shellcode is fine, the issue was actually an update to the gcc compiler which changes how the prolog/epilog are handled when code executes. When a program starts, the compiler-generated code puts the return address on the stack, but it does so using a new pattern. The executing program no longer uses the return addresses directly by popping it into the instruction pointer (IP). Instead, it pops the stack value into `%ecx` and then uses the contents at the address `%ecx-4` (for 32-bit machines) as the return address. Therefore, the way I was trying to do it was never going to work even with the protections turned off. This behavior only affects `main()` and not functions called by main. So a simple solution would be to place the contents of main into another function `foo()` and call foo() from main() as depicted below.

```
char shellcode[] = 
    "\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46"
    "\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1"
    "\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";
void foo()
{
    int *ret;
    ret = (int *)&ret + 4; 
    (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}

int main()
{
  foo();
}
```

Here is a question that is related to this answer.
[Understanding new gcc prologue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886429/understanding-new-gcc-prologue)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that could go wrong here:

- The store of the shell code address is optimized away because it is derived from a stack variable, and nothing reads from the stack afterwards.
- The store is optimized away because it is out of bounds.
- The offset calculation from the local variable is wrong, so the shellcode address does not overwrite the return address.  (This is what happens when I compile your example.)
- The execution is redirect, but the shellcode does not run because it is located in the non-executable `.data` segment.  (That would cause the process to terminate with a signal, though).

Comment: How were you able to determine that the shellcode isn't overwriting the return address?

Comment: I do get a seg fault when I run in gdb.

Comment: @user3431573 I read the machine code, looking at how the stack pointer is updated.

Comment: I'm probably going to sound like a complete noob but you were able to deduce that from looking at the hex!?

Comment: I ran the compiled `main` function through a disassembler. (This part is not about the shellcode, it's about the code redirecting to the shellcode.)

Comment: Ahhh ok I see will any disassmber do?